How to validate whatsapp api x-hub-signature-256 in NodeJS?
I'm building a whatsapp chatbot for my company and I'm using Nodejs (with Fastify) + whatsapp cloud api. On the docs, it's saying I don't need to validate the x-hub-signature-256, but as the docs says: I should do it. I can validate the hash for text messages, but can't validate for audio and image messages.
So my code looks similar to the following:
index.ts:
app.post(
    "/",
    async (
      request: FastifyRequest<{
        Body: WhatsappReceivedMessage;
      }>,
      reply
    ) => {
      const xHubSignature = request.headers["x-hub-signature-256"] as string;
      const body = request.body;

      if (!xHubSignature) {
        console.log("Missing X-Hub-Signature-256 header");
        return reply.status(403).send("Forbidden");
      }

      const expectedSignature = generateWPPSignature(
        JSON.stringify(body),
        env.WPP_SECRET
      );

      if (!validateWPPSignature(expectedSignature, xHubSignature)) {
        console.warn("Invalid X-Hub-Signature-256");
        return reply.status(403).send("Forbidden");
      }

      const message = request.body.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages[0];

      if (message.type === "text") {
        const business_phone_number_id =
          request.body.entry?.[0].changes?.[0].value?.metadata?.phone_number_id;

          console.log("message from", message.from);
          console.log("aa", message.id)

          try {
            const sendMessage = await axios({
              method: "POST",
              url: `https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/${business_phone_number_id}/messages`,
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${env.WPP_API_TOKEN}`,
              },
              data: {
                messaging_product: "whatsapp",
                recipient_type: "individual",
                to: message.from,
                type: "template",
                template: {
                  name: env.WPP_TEMPLATE_NAME,
                  language: {
                    code: "pt_BR"
                  },
                  components: [
                    {
                      type: "button",
                      sub_type: "flow",
                      index: "0",
                      parameters: [
                        {
                          type: "action",
                          action: {
                            flow_token: env.WPP_FLOW_TOKEN,   //optional, default is "unused"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
            });
          
            console.log("Sent message:", sendMessage.data);
          } catch (error: any) {
            console.error("Error sending message:", error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
          }
          
          try {
            const markMessageAsRead = await axios({
              method: "POST",
              url: `https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/${business_phone_number_id}/messages`,
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${env.WPP_API_TOKEN}`,
              },
              data: {
                messaging_product: "whatsapp",
                status: "read",
                message_id: message.id,
              },
            });
          
            console.log("Marked message as read:", markMessageAsRead.data);
          } catch (error: any) {
            console.error("Error marking message as read:", error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
          }
          
      }

      return reply.send("OK");
    }
  );

generateWPPSignature and validateWPPSignature functions:
import crypto from 'node:crypto';

export function generateWPPSignature(request_body: string, wpp_secret: string) {
  return crypto.createHmac('sha256', wpp_secret).update(request_body, 'utf-8').digest('hex');
}

export function validateWPPSignature(expected_hash: string, xHubSignature: string) {

  const signatureHash = xHubSignature.split('sha256=')[1]

  const isValid = crypto.timingSafeEqual(
    Buffer.from(expected_hash),
    Buffer.from(signatureHash)
  )

  return isValid
}

EDIT:
I forgot to show the request body for each message type
text message:
{
  object: 'whatsapp_business_account',
  entry: [
    {
      id: '*****',
      changes: [
        {
          value: {
            messaging_product: 'whatsapp',
            metadata: {
              display_phone_number: '****',
              phone_number_id: '****',
            },
            contacts: [
              {
                profile: { name: 'Borgim' },
                wa_id: '*****'
              }
            ],
            messages: [
              {
                from: '****',
                id: '****',
                timestamp: '1729522753',
                text: { body: 'borgim' },
                type: 'text'
              }
            ]
          },
          field: 'messages'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

audio message
{
  object: 'whatsapp_business_account',
  entry: [
    {
      id: '*****',
      changes: [
        {
          value: {
            messaging_product: 'whatsapp',
            metadata: {
              display_phone_number: '*****',
              phone_number_id: '*****'
            },
            contacts: [
              {
                profile: { name: 'Borgim' },
                wa_id: '*****'
              }
            ],
            messages: [
              {
                from: '*****',
                id: '*****',
                timestamp: '1729522882',
                type: 'audio',
                audio: {
                  mime_type: 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus',
                  sha256: 'AgVhafj7IPRqDdj4ym+KqqrCmm6fXvNOSwKl434IEV8=',
                  id: '*****',
                  voice: true
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          field: 'messages'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

this code works fine for text messages, but when try to process image or audio messages, I can't compare the hashes. Does anyone know how can I proceed?

When the body is a file, I assume you can't use the json.stringify method unless it is a base64 string.

Hi @ManuelSpigolon. I figured it might be this, but the body for text messages and audio messages is close, just changing the "type" property and some IDs. In media messages, it doesn't pass the media content in the body, instead it just passes some IDs. I don't know if I'm missing something. I've updated my question showing the request bodies. Thanks for the answer
